# Can't enter text into HTML input field on Android mobile website, though input gets focus

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I am trying to view my website in the default browser that comes with my Samsung Galaxy Android phone, but it isn't working properly. I can't seem to enter text into a popup login form. When I try to enter my username the HTML input gets focus and the predictive search starts to work, but it won't enter any text into the input field. I can however enter text successfully into other form inputs that are on my page (these forms are not in popup divs).

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that my form is in a absolute positioned div that appears when the user clicks on the login button.

A couple of my colleagues have tried the page on their android phones and are able to enter text as they should, so I think this is a OS/Browser specific problem. I'm running Android 2.3.3 and using the default browser that comes with that.

This is the css for the the login div and form inputs:

```
.loginPanel{z-index:2000;width:341px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px;border-bottom-right-   radius:3px;background:#3DB44A;position:absolute;clear:left;margin:0 0 0     0;top:57px;display:none;padding:5px 0 0 0;}

.loginPanel input[type=text]{width:280px;height:40px;margin:0 auto;display:block;border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;font:bold 12px Arial;color:#353535;padding:0 10px;}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="loginPanel" style="margin-left: -246px; display: block;">
<form id="user_form_login" class="global_form_box" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/login" method="post">
<div class="close">
<a id="login-close" href="#">
<img alt="" src="themes/network90v2/landing_images/close.png">
</a>
</div>
<div class="clear">
<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
</div>
<div id="username-required" class="form-label-required">
<span class="form-block-required">email is required</span>
</div>
<div id="username-invalid" class="form-label-required">
<span class="form-block-required">email is not valid</span>
</div>
<div class="clear">
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
</div>
<div id="password-required" class="form-label-required">
<span class="form-block-required">password is required</span>
</div>
<div class="clear forgotten">
<span>
<a href="/user/auth/forgot">Forgot Password?</a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="submit-top"></div>
<div class="remember submitMain">
<input id="login-submit" type="submit" value="Login">
<input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" tabindex="4">
```

Remember Me

I'm hoping that this can be fixed using CSS. If anyone has a solution/ had the same problem, I would really appreciate your help.

PS I would really prefer to keep the login form as a popup, so Ideally any solutions will allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with a mobile site that behaved strangely on Android 2.2.  From memory, I had to use `position: fixed` instead of absolute to get around it.  Not sure if that will work with your design though.